# Apple Maps Location Marker like in Find Friends App

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have an app where I want the user to place a marker on a map and drag a circle to define a range around that notification, exactly as in Apple's Find Friends App (when you pick one of your friends and subscribe for notifications when he arrives or leaves a certain location).

Looks like this:
[image]

The marker can be dragged and moved like always, but the solid circle on the right side is used to define a range around the marker.

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement that? Maybe someone has already implemented something like this and wants to share his code :-).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found some very useful sourcecode. Here it is, in case somebody else needs it as well: https://github.com/d0ping/DBMapSelectorViewController